# How to include file contents in Rust compiled binary?

Tags: rust

```rust
const fn get_dockerfile() -> String {
    let mut file_content = String::new();
    let mut file = File::open("dockers/PostgreSql").expect("Failed to read the file");
    file.read_to_string(&mut file_content);
    file_content
}

const DOCKERFILE: String = get_dockerfile();
```

I'm writing a Rust script to manage docker operations.

1. I want to include docker-file content in my binary executable.
2. I thought by assigning that content into a `const` variable I could achieve this but I am getting this error:

```rust
error[E0723]: mutable references in const fn are unstable
 --> src/main.rs:9:5
  |
9 |     file.read_to_string(&mut file_content);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`include_str!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_str.html) macro to include strings from files at compile time.

```rust
const DOCKERFILE: &str = include_str!("dockers/PostgreSql");
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use the [`include_str!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_str.html) macro:

```
let dockerfile = include_str!("Dockerfile");
```

This will embed the file contents in the binary as a string. The variable `dockerfile` is initialized as a pointer to this string. It's not even necessary to make it a constant, since this initialization is basically free.

If your file isn't valid UTF-8, you can use [`include_bytes!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_bytes.html) instead.